# File Importation - Php - Mysql

Tags: php, sql, file, import

I am creating a website. I have a file with several columns and about 50,000 rows and I must import this file through that website to the mysql database.

First of all, I would like to know what type of file is light for this type of task (txt, xls, xls or others).

On the other hand, I would like to know, through a website I have an execution time, therefore, how do I delay the time necessary to import all the rows of the file.

Finally, if the import is only done by updating the rows that I already have and adding the ones that I do not have, computationally speaking, it is bad to search with a "select" statement and then do the "update" (2 queries to the database to to update)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: 1) csv might be a good choice. Certainly easier than excel. 2) upload the file and then hand off the process to a background job e.g. triggered by Cron. 3) most databases have a way to do an "upsert" type of feature these days where it will insert a row if the key doesn't already exist, otherwise update.

Comment: !! Your answer is very clear, thank you !!